# how to simplify codes

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a next button.

theres no error i just want to simplify

```
Try
     lblcat.Text = ds.Tables("evaluation").Rows(cat)("QuestionCategory")
     txt1.Text = ds.Tables("evaluation").Rows(CurrentRow)("Question")
     txt2.Text = ds.Tables("evaluation").Rows(CurrentRow + 1)("Question")
     txt3.Text = ds.Tables("evaluation").Rows(CurrentRow + 2)("Question")
     txt4.Text = ds.Tables("evaluation").Rows(CurrentRow + 3)("Question")
     txt5.Text = ds.Tables("evaluation").Rows(CurrentRow + 4)("Question")
 Catch ex As Exception
 End Try
```

every click to the next button my category and questions change.
every click i want also to save in my database

```
Private Sub Save_commit()
 Dim con As New OleDbConnection
 Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
 Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
 Try
     'get connection string declared in the Module1.vb and assing it to conn variable
     con = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
     con.Open()
     cmd.Connection = con
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
     'I just use the textbox tag property to idetify if the data is new or existing.
     sSQL = "INSERT INTO evaluationresult ([Com])" & _
             "  VALUES (?)"
     cmd.CommandText = sSQL
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FacultyID", txtresult.Text)
     'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNumber", OleDbType.Numeric).Value
     'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Com", OleDbType.Numeric).Value
     ' cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Know", OleDbType.Numeric).Value
     'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teaching", OleDbType.Numeric).Value
     'cmd.Parameters.Addwithvallue("@man", OleDbType.Numeric).Value()
   'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ErrorToString)
     Finally
    con.Close()
     End Try
 End Sub
```

please improve

Comment: What do you want to improve? Looks fine to me.

Comment: everytime i click next iwant to save it to my database sir.,.,Com(tablefield) then another datas will appear then i will check radio buttons.,.,then add to similar id number (Know)(tablefield) and so on

Comment: sir my system is teachers evaluation

now
ihave table eval results
with fields
facultyID, Com, Know,Teaching,Manage
i have also a radio buttons to check for their evaluation

if they click next button the first total of radiobuttons will be save at com
then if i click next again the second rating of the user will be save at the (Know)
if i click again the third will be save at (Teaching)
and lastly total(Manage)
but in the same row only